# QGIS 2.12 Edit rendering styles for outputs not listing all outputs

Tags: qgis-2, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have built a model in QGIS 2.12 and have been using the **Edit rendering styles for outputs** to set the styles for the models output data. But I have come across an issue.

When I am configuring a particular model one of the outputs are not listed. As shown in the image, there is a line for the particular output but nothing else. Has anyone come across this issue before? If so what was your fix? if not does anyone have any pointers to get to the bottom of this?

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your model please? And are you using the **Distance matrix** tool in your model?

Comment: Hi Joseph - Thanks for your comment, I am using Distance matrix along with a number of others. What would you like to glean from the review in the model?

Comment: Ahh I see, it was just incase if you were trying to style the output of the Distance matrix tool as the output for this is a .csv file. I just assumed from the name of your model =). Otherwise that's something I don't think I have come across before.

Comment: Thanks Joseph =). The Output I am trying to style is a .DXF file that has been converted to .shp. This issue has occurred in the past so thought this time I would put it out to the community to see if we could sort it out. Thanks for your time Joseph.